# Limit # of results autocomplete jquery ui using slice function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have the same question as: [Limit results autocomplete jquery ui with slice function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12951773/limit-results-autocomplete-jquery-ui-with-slice-function) , been looking for a solution (other than hiding using CSS) for the past 2 hours or so.

I want to add this slice function, demo here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7617637/1607449

```
$("#auto").autocomplete({
source: function(request, response) {
    var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(myarray, request.term);

    response(results.slice(0, 10));
   }
});
```

And I would like it to work with the script in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/h5E6C/ (not my array/script but my setup is similar).

I'm looking for solutions to this question, so please don't respond with a suggestion to use PHP/SQL to filter the data before sending etc. Don't mean to be rude..

I can get either script to work independently of one another but not together :/

Comment: Why aren't you just using the minlength option?

Comment: because I'm using the search to look up room #s in a handful of buildings. If someone types in '2' or '5' it would be nice to have it start populating the results then. (in the off chance the room is only 1 number in length, (i.e room #8))

Comment: How about using the search event?

Comment: In what way? The search event doesn't affect the results once they are returned, it only prevents the search from happening if you assign it certain conditions to meet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, just needed to add

```
.slice(0, 10)
```

to the other response function.

Before:

```
function custom_source(request, response) {
    var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
    response($.grep(schools, function(value) {
        return matcher.test(value.value)
            || matcher.test(value.nickname);
    }));
}
```

After:

```
function custom_source(request, response) {
    var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
    response($.grep(schools, function(value) {
        return matcher.test(value.value)
            || matcher.test(value.nickname);
    }).slice(0, 10)
);
}
```

Thought I had tried that already but I must have placed the slice function in the wrong place before.