# jQuery UI autocomplete. Set number of suggestions to show

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-autocomplete, jquery-widgets

How can I set number of suggestions to show for jQuery UI autocomplete widget?

I cannot find any documentation regarding this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [limit results in jquery ui autocomplete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617373/limit-results-in-jquery-ui-autocomplete)

Answer (score 1):

There is no native way to limit results in jQuery UI autocomplete widget. You have two options to achieve your target:

1. You can limit returned results on the server side.
2. You can modify results on client side by slicing results array. You can check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617373/limit-results-in-jquery-ui-autocomplete).