# Limit the maximum visible values for Struts2 autocompleter

Tags: jquery, struts2, autocomplete, struts2-jquery

I am using struts2 autocompleter. When I click on the dropdown icon it gives all results. I have tried setting `maxlength` & `size` attributes but it doesnt work. Is there a way to limit the maximum number of values?? Or maybe add a scroll bar??
This is my autocompleter code :

```
 <s:url id="myURL" action="AutoComplete"/>    
 <sj:select 
 id="autooo"  
 name="echo" selectBoxIcon="true"
 label="Handle a List"
 href="%{myURL}" 
 list="govAdvCaseList" 
 listValue="case_No" 
 listKey="case_id" maxlength="5" 
 autocomplete="true"  size="5"
 loadMinimumCount="4" 
 />
```

Thanks In Advance :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Limit results in jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617373/limit-results-in-jquery-ui-autocomplete)

Comment: this is *good* question, struts2-jquery plugin should handle viewable area of the widget.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer [here](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#maxheight)

Applying this css worked for me. It created a scroll bar if not limiting the values

```
   <style>
  .ui-autocomplete {
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
   .ui-autocomplete {
    height: 100px;
  }
  </style>


<div class="ui-widget">
  auto completer here
</div>
```