# Can't use bootstrap fixed bottom navbar properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries

I have created a sticky footer by using bootstrap 3 fixed bottom navbar.It works fine normally , but at one page I have used a autocompleter so when autocompleter is shown , in that case my footer overlaps last 2-3 values of the autocompleter.

Code for footer :

```
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom" style="height:30px;">
   <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-7">
            <p class="navbar-text text-center"> Copyright <i class="fa fa-copyright"></i> </p> 
      </div>
      <div class = "col-md-6">

      </div>
      <div class = "col-md-2 col-xs 5">
         <p class="navbar-text text-right"> Beta Version </p>                  
      </div>        
   </div>      
   </div>
</div>  <!--  navbar for the footer ends -->
```

I have added a screenshot of problem :

[image]

Which shows the problem , as last few entries in my auto completer are overlapped by footer.

Comment: try adding z-index property to unhide.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jquery-ui autocomplete ?

If so, you can try to limiter the results in it. You can see this [Limit results in jQuery UI Autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617373/limit-results-in-jquery-ui-autocomplete)