# jqueryui autocomplete number of suggestions

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, limit, autosuggest

I'm working with the jqueryUI autocomplete script. The thing is that I want to limit the number of suggestions it provides to 6, as it is offering too much suggestions. This is the script:

```
$.get('file.txt', function(x) {

    var i;
    var pos = 0;
    var availableTags = [];

    x = x.split(/[\#\n]+/);

    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i = i + 4)
      availableTags[pos++] = x[i];

    console.log(availableTags);

    $(function() {
      $("#search").autocomplete({source: availableTags});
      response(availableTags.slice(0, 6));
    });

    }, 'text');
```

I spotted and [excellent solution by Andrew Whitaker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617373/limit-results-in-jquery-ui-autocomplete) but can't make it work. He suggested to use

```
response(availableTags.slice(0, 6));
```

Any solution to limit the number of suggestions on my script?

Answer (score 2):

you can override _renderMenu function to display maximum N items

```
$.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderMenu = function( ul, items ) {
   var self = this;
   $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
      if (index < 10) // here we define how many results to show
         {self._renderItem( ul, item );}
      });
}
```

or with slice response:

```
$("#search").autocomplete({ 
    source: function(request, response) {
        var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(availableTags, request.term);

        response(results.slice(0, 6));
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot michal pavlik, works almost perfect but affects to the html result and css. Do you mind if I wait for a simpler answer?

Comment: sure, I edited my post and added simpler solution with slice results.

Comment: Well, the second just doesn't work :'( but it's maybe my fault. I edited the code in my question in order to show you how I included your code. Do you spot any mistakes?

Comment: you don't have closed brace after autocomplete function. There should be `});` on 3rd line from bottom

Comment: I'm so sorry mike, man, but it kees not working... :(( updated in my question too

Comment: It might be related to the source, which used to be source: availableTags

Comment: before autocomplete you have `$(function() {` which should'nt be there

Comment: Jesuschrist, don't be angry with me but it doesn't work. I feel I'm driving you frantic :( Updated my question

Comment: Your first code (now in the first square of your answer) is just great. The only problem it gives me is that, when I clic on the suggestion, it is not written in the input text field. is that easy to fix?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    var limit = 3;
    var tags = [
      "hello","hi", "him", 'here',"his", "honour", "banquet"
    ];
    $( "#search" ).autocomplete({
        source: tags.slice(0, limit),

        });
});
```

Please find above solution and let me know if it works for you.